# switch statement with macros in C with visual studio 2010

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, macros

I'm trying to do something like this

```
#define GETCART1 0;
#define GETCART2 1;

void helper(int *Array,int length,int counter, int option){
    if (length > counter){
        switch(option){
        case (GETCART1) :

            break;
        }//switch
    }
}
```

and I get compile error when I replace `GETCART1` with `0` its works fine. Why is that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's wrong with this 1988 C code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8640818/whats-wrong-with-this-1988-c-code)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Drop the semicolons from the defines.

```
#define GETCART1 0;
                  ^ Drop this
```

If you don't, by the time the preprocessor is done, your code will end up looking like this:

```
switch(option){
case (0;) :
       ^
    break;
}
```

Comment: does this is compiler based> because i dont get any error without ; in define in gcc

Comment: @Mr.32 This isn't compiler dependent. That's the whole point, it works **without the semicolons**.