# Using an Array with a #define value in C

Tags: c, eclipse, code-composer

I am using some code from Jack Ganssles debouce [tutorial](http://www.ganssle.com/debouncing-pt2.htm), and trying to get it to work on an MSP430 using Texas Instruments Code Composer Studio v5.5 (based on Eclipse).  I am having an issue with an integer array, that I am using a define value called MAXCHECKS in.

```
#define MAXCHECKS 8;
int Debounced_state;            // Debounced state of the switches
int state[MAXCHECKS];           // Array that maintains bounce status
int Index = 0;                  // Pointer into state
```

This line *int state[MAXCHECKS];* throws up 2 errors #17 expected "]" and #171 expected a declaration.  If I change MAXCHECKS to a value of say 8 or 10 the code builds and loads fine, although it does not debounce the switches, but that is something I can work on as not set the timer up yet.

The code that the define and variables work with is as follows

```
int i,j;
state[Index] = (P1IN & 0x0088);
++Index;
j = 0xFF;

for(i=0; i<MAXCHECKS; i++)
{
    j &= state[i];          
}   

Debounced_state = j;            
if (Index>=MAXCHECKS)
{
    Index = 0;
}
```

I figure it must be something I am missing but at this point unsure hence the question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's wrong with this 1988 C code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8640818/whats-wrong-with-this-1988-c-code)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the semicolon at the end of the macro definition

```
#define MAXCHECKS 8;
```

The pre-processor expands the line in question to

```
int state[8;];
```

which causes the compiler error.

Comment: Cheers Martin I feel like an idiot now with such a simple error!