# Compile errors after adding V8 to my project (C2143, C2059, ..)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, visual-studio-2005, v8

i've recently added Google's V8 to a MSVC2005 project which is also using Qt and i haven't been able to compile it since.
The defines are giving me a lot of problems, for example
in V8's token.h there is

```
#define T(name, string, precedence) name,
enum Value {
TOKEN_LIST(T, T)
NUM_TOKENS
};
```

The line TOKEN_LIST(T, T) yields an error C2143 ('}' missing before '{'), also error C2059 (syntax error '{'), also C2334 (token before '{'; visible function text is skipped). This repeats itself a couple of times.

I have searched through SO and through Microsoft's database and tested various things, for example using /clr, which broke Qt. I also used #undef before including the "v8.h" file for possibly existing definitions to be removed.

Can anyone help with this? Is there a standard procedure to fix errors like this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the conflicting macro definitions by searching for differences between the [preprocessed code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/277267/894321) generated for `token.h` with and without the `#include <windows.h>`.

For example, for "token.h", the errors occur at the definition of the `enum Value` so you have to look at the preprocessed definition of that `enum` in both cases. So with

```
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <token.h>
```

you get:

```
enum Value {
    ...
    INSTANCEOF, , NOT, BIT_NOT, (0x00010000L), TYPEOF, void, BREAK,
    ...
    SWITCH, void, THROW,
    ...
    FUTURE_STRICT_RESERVED_WORD, const, EXPORT,
    ...
};
```

instead of:

```
enum Value {
    ...
    INSTANCEOF, IN, NOT, BIT_NOT, DELETE, TYPEOF, VOID, BREAK,
    ...
    SWITCH, THIS, THROW, 
    ... 
    FUTURE_STRICT_RESERVED_WORD, CONST, EXPORT,
    ...
};
```

with only `#include <token.h>`.

Comment: How can i explicitly remove the windows.h include? I did not add it and it's not in the token.h. Sorry for my lack of knowledge and thanks.

Comment: @Traveller: You could for example create a new .cpp file, with only 2 lines `#include <windows.h>` and `#include <path/to/token.h>`, and run that file through the preprocessor.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately the files match.

Comment: They didn't when I tried... By comparing the `Value` enum in both cases, I found 5 macros that were replaced by something else: `IN`, `DELETE`, `VOID`, `THIS`, `CONST`. Maybe you have to disable precompiled headers for the file.

Comment: So i cleaned the project, disabled precompiled headers and used windows.h + token.h one time and only token.h the other, but the generated .i-files match completely. Hmm

Comment: @Traveller I retested starting with an empty Win32 project in Visual C++ 2010 (I was using "gcc -E" + wine's windows.h on linux before) and it seems to work, so I'm not sure what you did differently...