# How does a preprocessor macro work?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

```
#define B 100+B
main()
{
    int i= B;
}
```

I know it's wrong, but just out of curiosity, when I compile it I get this weird error:

> "B was not declared in this scope".

Why is it so? If this error was because the compiler removes the macro after its substitution then how does the following code worked fine, when *B* must have been removed before it was made available to *A* ?

```
#define B 100
#define A 100+B
main()
{
    int i= B;
    int j =A;
}
```

Comment: That’s invalid C++, by the way.

Comment: Placing spaces on only one side of the `=` operator is so ugly…

Comment: @RadekSlupik But at least they're on different sides in the two lines, which makes it look kind of funny.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer: then perhaps you will like this one: http://blog.aerojockey.com/post/iocccsim

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's the output of the preprocessor:

```
gcc -E x.c
# 1 "x.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "x.c"

main()
{
    int i= 100+B;
}
```

As you can see, it did the substituion. Now comes the compile step which fails because there's no `B` declared.

The other code is fine, here's the output:

```
main()
{
    int i= 100;
    int j =100+100;
}
```

Comment: *Preprocessor*, not *precompiler*

Comment: @cirronimbo: if you have visual studio: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/277258/c-c-source-file-after-preprocessing

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: yeah, I saw that, but unfortunately I work on code::blocks 10.5, not on visual studio, and I really have no clue how to generate this preprocessor output even after looking at the above code, in code::blocks.

Comment: @cirronimbo: that's just an IDE, a front-end. use a command shell, and type the appropriate command for the compiler (gcc/msvc).

Answer (score 9):

Macro expansion isn't done recursively, if the macro name appears in the replacement text, it isn't expanded again. So with

```
#define B 100 + B
```

a replacement of `B` yields the token sequence `100 + B` and `B` is not expanded again (if it were, you'd have an infinite recursion). So the compiler sees a reference to the undeclared variable `B` after the preprocessor finished.

But in

```
#define B 100
#define A 100 + B
```

when the macro `A` is expanded, the macro name `B` appears in the replacement text. Then `B` is expanded and the compiler sees `100 + 100` which contains no references to undeclared variables.

Comment: This answer should get a tick. Just sayin'.

Answer (score 0):

macro replacement are simple text operation.you can debug this type of problem in a simple step by step compile.

use cc -E filename.c -O filename.i

for generate extended c code

vi filename.i  for reading pure/extended c code