# Online Preprocessor for C++

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

**I have:**

1. C++ code with lots of complicated MACROS (#define bla bla ...)
2. And the usage (instantiation) of those MACROS

**I need:**

A tool (online for example) that will simply do the instantiation of the MACROS (or the system of macros) and show the resultant code.

**Example:**

*Input:*

```
#define AAA(a,b) if ((a) > (b))

AAA(1, f1(10))
```

*Output:*

```
if ((1) > (f1(10)))
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [C/C++ source file after preprocessing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/277258/c-c-source-file-after-preprocessing)

Comment: Use your **compiler**: For example, in GCC you can say, `gcc -E -P file.c`.

Comment: Why close vote? This is a programming related question!

Comment: Compilers have this built in. Which one are you using? Also, this is a terrible macro for C++; it should be an inline function like almost all macros.

Comment: I work on Windows with MVS, and I dont want to see my file after preprocessing because it would be big and with lots of unnecessary information!!!

Comment: The close vote is for a duplicate question.

Comment: It is not duplicate! I have already mentioned the difference with the one that you mentioned Luchian Grigore.

Comment: @Narek then you should specify that in the question. Edit it and clarify that it's not a duplicate because you only want the macro expansion of the current file, not the full preprocessing that will also expand `#include` directives.

Comment: @KerrekSB sometimes you have reasons to use C preprocessor and you do not have any C compiler installed, like when working with GLSL (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22496874/is-there-a-tool-to-get-preprocessed-output-of-a-glsl-shader/69140739#69140739)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `gcc` option would be [-E](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.0/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options) and then your filename.

With the MSVC `cl.exe` the solution is also [/E](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3xkfswhy.aspx).

Comment: What about not precompiling the whole file or project but a code snippet only? And what about doing this with Visual studio at least.

Comment: Added that, and sorry for the typo, for a second or two I gave the option as `-e`.

Comment: Thanks, but still I deal with a very big project, and I need to prcompile only a small snippet. No faster way?

Comment: Not one that I would be aware of.

Comment: @Narek Copy snippet to an empty tmp.c file, then run `gcc -E tmp.c` on that.

Comment: Good answer. Would like to add, if you want it online just go to http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/ add `-E` and remove `&& a.out` in the command line.

Comment: @Predelnik Thank you for being the only person who actually answered the OP's question instead of giving a "don't do it" answer like everyone else did.