# How to generate pre-processed C code

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C/C++ source file after preprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277258/c-c-source-file-after-preprocessing)

I am looking to generate all of the pre-processed c code for an application, in this case apache. I downloaded the source code for Apache, and have been running the following command “gcc -c -save-temps *.c” and have tried */*.c. When running either of these commands, I get numerous errors, some of which include:

```
server/core.c:17:17: fatal error: apr.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
server/core_filters.c:22:17: fatal error: apr.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
server/eoc_bucket.c:17:19: fatal error: httpd.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

I am fairly certain the program SHOULD compile correctly since  it came right from the Apache website. What should I be doing in order to generate the necessary pre-processed c code. Should I be using the makefile somehow?

The application I am attempting to analyze the source code with which requires the pre-processed c code can found [here](http://ropas.snu.ac.kr/mecc/)

Thank you for your help everyone.

Comment: `gcc -c` won't generate preprocessed source, it will emit object code instead.

Comment: Thanks. What is the command I should be using then?

Comment: `gcc -E` is what you're looking for.

Comment: @H2CO3: You should make that an answer, since that's pretty much all there is to it.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Maybe, but that doesn't resolve the missing headers' problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(So, just to repeat myself by repeating others who repeat me...)

`gcc -c` produces object code. If you want the preprocessor to be invoked, use `gcc -E`.

Comment: That seems to work, and I can definitly give credit.

Comment: For the generated "pre-processor files", if I wanted to reference everyone in all subdirectories, how would I do that? Right now, I am trying:

Comment: Also, for the gcc-E option, I get many compilation issues. Is there a way I should be running this command through a makefile or something?