# cvSaveImage was not declared in this scope?

Tags: file, opencv, header

My code worked perfectly for months until today. Its in C++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
IplImage* img = cvLoadImage("C:/Users/Amadeus/Documents/H1/cat.png");

int result=cvSaveImage("C:/Users/Amadeus/Documents/H1/cat.png",img); <----- Problem

return 0;
}
```

It keeps saying "cvSaveImage was not declared in this scope". Files that would compile perfectly before all say it now. I don't understand why it worked for many months and today it says it wasn't declared. I even opened files that I knew worked for sure and even those didn't. It's like the header files are corrupt or something? What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, something changed in your system. I assume you don't know what exactly. The good point to start finding it out is to view your file after preprocessing is done. See for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277258/c-c-source-file-after-preprocessing) on how to do this. Most probably you are pointing wrong or corrupted `cv.h` file for some reason.

By the way, why aren't you using modern C++ OpenCV functions `imread` and `imwrite`? They are in *all* ways better than their old C ancestors.

Comment: Thanks! Will keep that in mind. I reinstalled OpenCV, which was extremely tedious work, and its working again. I believe I may have accidentally edited the header file after an unexpected error occurred yesterday.