# What does CV_SWAP macro do?

Tags: c, opencv

I couldn't find reference to it in the [official docs](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/refman.html).

Comment: Just run it through the preprocessor and see what it turns into.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/277258/c-c-source-file-after-preprocessing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It [switches two values around](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/7c4e3715b324e0b018059ca78e7544077e9213ac/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/types_c.h#L187):

```
#define CV_SWAP(a,b,t) ((t) = (a), (a) = (b), (b) = (t))
```