# Set a breakpoint in a macro in Visual Studio

Tags: c, visual-studio-2012, macros, breakpoints

Is there a way to set a breakpoint for C code in Visual Studio inside a `#define`? When I set the breakpoint it isn't reached, and the rest code continues to be executed. For example:

```
#define YY_USER_ACTION sn_yylloc.first_line = sn_yylloc.last_line =sn_yylineno; \
sn_yylloc.first_column = sn_yycolumn; \
sn_yylloc.last_column = sn_yycolumn + sn_yyleng -1; \
sn_yycolumn += sn_yyleng;
```

The code is a lexer generated by Flex, but that's really of no importance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This `#define` is being expanded by the preprocessor *before* compilation. What you could do is try to run with the Visual Studio debugger with this code instead of the original code (read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277258/c-c-source-file-after-preprocessing) about getting your hands on the preprocessed code).