# Why no error is thrown on declaring vector of vector of int using #define

Tags: c++, vector

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

#define vi vector<int>
#define vvi vector<vi>

int main() {
    vi v(10, -1);
    vvi vv(10, v);
    for(int i=0; i<vv.size(); i++){
        for(int j=0; j<vv[i].size(); j++){
            cout << vv[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

When I compile the above code, no error is reported and it runs fine ([see this](http://ideone.com/cb1Lxr)). But when I declare a vector of vector of int using `vector < vector < int>>` an error occurs because I have not put a space between the right angle brackets. So why is no error reported in the first case when all that `#define` does is replace the occurrences of `vi` with `vector<int>` and `vvi` with `vector< vector< int>>`?

Comment: The preprocessor works with streams of tokens, and the two `>` are separate tokens.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason you're not getting the error with the `#define` method is that the preprocessor is intelligently inserting breaks. If you pass that code through only the preprocessor stage (`gcc -E`, for example), you'll see something like:

```
int main() {
    vector<int> v(10,-1);
    vector<vector<int> > vv(10,v);           // <<-- see space here.
    for(int i=0; i<vv.size(); i++){
        for(int j=0; j<vv[i].size(); j++){
            cout << vv[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

The *reason* why this happens has to do with the phases of translation as dictated by the ISO C++ standard.

Section 2.2 of C++11 <sup>(a)</sup> states that there are nine translation phases. Phase 3 is the splitting of the source file into preprocessing tokens and white space.

The important thing there is the tokenisation, so that `vector<vi>` is the set of preprocessing tokens `{vector, <, vi, >}`, it is *not* the simplistic text given in the macro replacement section. While a *simplistic* text substitution of:

```
#define vi vector<int>
#define vvi vector<vi>
vvi xyzzy;
```

would result in:

```
vector<vector<int>> xyzzy;
```

what you *actually* end up with is the preprocessing token set:

```
{vector, <, vector, <, int, >, >, WHITESPACE, xyzzy, ;}
```

Then, at phase 7, the standard states:

> Each preprocessing token is converted into a token.

So, there's no recombining of the two `>` tokens into a single one despite the fact a simple reading of the source may suggest that.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Keep in mind that, though I'm quoting the C++11 parts of the standard to ensure the answer is more up-to-date, this particular problem is a C++03 one. C++11 actually fixes the parser so that multiple `>` characters will close a template argument list where reasonable (C++03 always treated it as the right-shift operator).

`C++11 14.2, section 3` specifies this:

> When parsing a template-argument-list, the first non-nested `>` is taken as the ending delimiter rather than a greater-than operator. Similarly, the first non-nested `>>` is treated as two consecutive but distinct `>` tokens ...

Comment: Holy cow, I had no idea the preprocessor did that.

Comment: How are you seeing the code after the pre processing stage? Is there some way to see just the preprocessed code on windows also?

Comment: @NikunjBanka: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/277258/c-c-source-file-after-preprocessing

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs because in C++03, the double angle brackets are interpreted as the right shift operator `>>`.  In C++11, the language was altered so that it is interpreted as closing the template arguments instead, so it should compile without errors in C++11 mode.  You can work around this by putting a space between the closing angle brackets, e.g. `vector<vector<int> >`.

Also, don't use `#define` to define type aliases like this; use `typedef` instead, as that's exactly what it's intended for.

Comment: Adam you are correct in saying that no errors will be reported in C++11 but I am working on C++ 4.8.1 . However I have got the answer in paxdiablo's answer.