# Class keyword followed by two words ?! cpp

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I encountered this code:

```
NAMESPACE_NCO_BEGIN

class NCO_VIEWS_DECLSPEC MyView:
    public CWnd
    { 
    };

NAMESPACE_NCO_END
```

What does the `NCO_VIEWS_DECLSPEC` mean?

`MyView` is class name.

If possible try to explain `NAMESPACE_NCO_BEGIN` and `NAMESPACE_NCO_END`.

Comment: They are probably preprocessor macros.  See if you can find their `#define` lines.

Comment: They are most probably `declspec` for `import`/`export` this class in that dll.

Comment: Probably `__declspec(dllimport)` or `__declspec(dllexport)`.

Comment: I've edited your question to improve the formatting. Please check that it still matches the code you're asking about.

Comment: The `NCO_VIEWS_DECLSPEC` can't be found on Google, which means it is probably a macro from a proprietary library. It is therefore very difficult to give a 100% accurate answer. A few clever guesses have been made already, though.

Comment: If you cannot easily find definition of NCO_VIEWS_DECLSPEC in the source code, then enable preprocessor output and have a look how the symbol was expanded.  (See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/277258/c-c-source-file-after-preprocessing)

Comment: In Visual Studio, you can generally right click and select "Go To Definition". Makes it easy to find out what that stuff means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All three are macros. Somewhere in the code, possibly in some included header file, there must be `#define`s for them. `NCO_VIEWS_DECLSPEC` most certainly translates to some compiler-specific class attribute, e.g. `__declspec( dllexport)` for Microsoft Visual C++. Look here for a detailed example: [Using dllimport and dllexport in C++ Classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/81h27t8c.aspx)