# Error 1 error LNK1104 after change Preprocess to a File

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, linker, c-preprocessor

I had to use a preprocessor, so I changed:

> Configuration Properties -> C++ -> Preprocessor -> Preprocess to a
>   File -> Yes

And got the error:

> Error 1   error LNK1104: cannot open file 'Debug\asnreal.obj'

The solution to this problem:

> I had to add quotes around the path to my .lib file in
>   Project->Properties->Configuration
>   Properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies .

I do not understand what kind of file .lib? Where is it? In my project, it is not. What do I need to specify in **Additional Dependencies**? I tried to add the path to debug my project in quotation marks, but nothing happens.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler outputs either the `.obj` file or the preprocessed file. When you enable the preprocessor output you effectively disable the output of the `.obj` file.

The VS doesn't take this in account and starts the linker anyway. Since you didn't output an `.obj` file the linker can't find it.

You can get much more in trouble when you have an old `.obj` file in place and changes in the source code generates new preprocessed output but don't get into the linked executable.

Comment: Thanks. In a default VS2019 setup, the preprocessed files have the [i extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28178790/which-file-is-generated-after-preprocessing-of-a-c-program). Added a request in the [form of a comment](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/comments/888419/view.html) so the jump link in the Error List directs to the relevant section in the description.