# LNK1181: cannot open input file

Tags: visual-studio, linker-errors

I've successfully generated a 64-bit library called "myLibrary.lib" in project A using Visual Studio 2010.

Now I've another project B that uses "myLibrary.lib". I include the header files required to use "myLibrary.lib" in project B. Added the .lib into my project and added an entry for it in Linker>Input>Additional Dependencies.

When I try to build, I get an error "LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file myLibrary.lib".

Things I've tried:

- Tried to the path of my .lib file in Linker>General>Additional
  Library Directories
  If I do this, then I get unreferenced  function errors for the ones I'm using from .lib
- Tried giving my .lib name in quotes along with full path in
  Linker>Input>Additional Dependencies
  If I do this, then I get unreferenced  function errors for the ones I'm using from .lib
- Made sure there are no spaces in my lib name
- Checked file permissions
- Tried building on Visual Studio 2017 and still get same error

Is there anything else that I can try to workaround this error?

Comment: For me, it turned out to be the *Preprocess to a File* option. See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28494509/error-1-error-lnk1104-after-change-preprocess-to-a-file).

Answer (score 1):

Based on the things you have tried, it seems you are going in the right direction. Few months ago, I have faced this problem in my VS 2010. I am getting an error like this

```
Error   1940    error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'element.lib'
```

I could not understand, whats going on, The file that the program is search for `element.lib` is there in that folder, but I do not understand, why it is showing error, then I tried few more things, as listed below

1. Either disable incremental linking, by going to

> -> Project Properties 
>   -> Configuration Properties 
>   -> Linker (General) 
>   -> Enable Incremental Linking -> "No (/INCREMENTAL:NO)"

2. cvtres.exe, file error in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\BIN\cvtres.exe` and one at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\BIN\amd64\cvtres.exe`, Make sure you are using the latest version in both of these locations.
3. This one is tricky, another possible cause for LNK1181 is that a long file name with embedded spaces was not enclosed in quotation marks. In that case, the linker will only recognize a file name up to the first space, and then assume a file extension of .obj. Make sure the file name length including the file path is less than the characters specified for windows OS, i.e. 128characters including spaces...