# Initializer is not a constant only with certain functions

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

If I try compile the following and I have /O2 optimisation on, then it doesn't compile:

```
#include <math.h>


double myfunc(double arg) { return 5.4; };


double (*f[])(double) = { 
    myfunc,
    fabs, 
   // floor,  // THESE TWO TRIGGER THE ERROR
   // ceil, // initialiser is not a constant 
    sqrt
};
```

Only the floor and ceil functions trigger the error. If I put this code in a cpp file it compiles fine, but it seems MSVC's compiler is bugged, or am I doing something wrong? Error only happens on /O2, not /O1 or disabled. I'm on Visual Studio Version 17.7.6. Windows SDK version is 10.0 (latest installed version).

Comment: @ikegami Only happens with /O2 on, /O1 and disabled compile. MAcros wouldn't do that, would they?

Comment: @ikegami: Even if they are macros, the C standard says they have to be usable as function pointers.  The header could do `#define floor(x) /* whatever */`, but when `floor` is encountered without a following `(`, you are supposed to get the genuine function and not the macro.

Comment: Just as a check, you're sure you are compiling this as C, not as C++?

Comment: Please [edit] and show the Windows SDK version and the platform toolset in the General tab in the project settings.

Comment: @Jabberwocky SDK version 10.0 (latest installed version).

Comment: Compiles fine with `cl` on MSVC 2015

Comment: Can you post the output from the preprocessor?  See [**How do I see a C/C++ source file after preprocessing in Visual Studio?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277258/how-do-i-see-a-c-c-source-file-after-preprocessing-in-visual-studio)

Comment: @AndrewHenle I am not OP, but I did that myself earlier. Searching the generated .i file for `ceil` or `floor` shows the expected declarations from ucrt\corecrt_math.h including `__declspec(dllimport) double    __cdecl ceil(  double _X);` and `__declspec(dllimport) double    __cdecl floor(  double _X);`. I thought it might have something to do with the `__declspec(dllimport)` because the declarations of `fabs` and `sqrt` did not have it (e.g. `double __cdecl fabs(  double _X);`), but other functions declared with `__declspec(dllimport)` (e.g. `cbrt`) worked fine in the initializer.

Comment: FWIW, I filed a bug report: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/C2099-initializer-is-not-a-constant-whe/10529106

Comment: @IanAbbott I'm standing by to upvote your answer.  :-)

Comment: @AndrewHenle It may be better to upvote the bug report. :-)

Comment: @IanAbbott Done.

Answer (score 3):

It is unrelated to the optimisation settings.

It is only because of the *Enable Intrinsic Functions* settings. If you set this to **NO**, it compiles fine. With this setting set to **Yes (/Oi)** I get the same errors.

- Visual Studio 2022 17.8.0
- Platform toolset : Visual Studio 2022 (v143)
- Windows SDK Version : 10.0.22621.0 (latest installed version)

[image]

Comment: From the screenshot, *Enable Intrinsic Functions* **is** an optimization setting, so your first sentence seems inconsistent with the rest of the answer.  I guess you probably mean that the issue is not related to optimization *level* or optimization *flags* (`/O2` *vs* `/O1` or other), but that doesn't seem right either, because the OP observes different behavior at different optimization levels.

Comment: Nope, I have enable instrinsic functions set to no, still doesn't compile. But I have a feeling something really weird is happening as I think that setting did something when I tried to compile something else.

Comment: I guess this counts as a bug in the compiler. Enabling intrinsic functions should only replace function *calls*.

Comment: @IanAbbott In my case disabling intrinsics still doesn't make it compile, but disabling /O2 works.

Comment: @Zebrafish Same for me.