# Efficient way of watching and evaluating pieces of code with parameters in C++ that are cascading macros

Tags: c++, macros, preprocessor, identifier, immediate-window

I work in the Visual Studio IDE. I inhered some C++ code where a lot of macros are defined: it's like a cascade of macros are referring to some other replacement, again referring to some other replacement, see below.

I come from a Matlab environment, so I'm super frustrated that if I want to watch the value if these variables in Autos/Locals, I have to walk down the cascade and paste the actual preprocessed identifier/string into the watch window. Also, I cannot paste the actual C++ code into the Immediate Window, as it cannot process these identifiers without them being replaced by the preprocessor first.

Is there any add-on that can do all the cascading/preproccesing for you when you want to paste stuff in the immediate window, where these identifiers are parts of more complex statements and you just want to paste it in and get the result?

Or any other solution?
I'm not experienced in C++, but my wild guess is this cannot be the actual good way of programming as it's so hard to develop the code further or understand it. It's gonna be near impossible to rewrite this program I got, but if you know of any improvements that can be made, you can let me know.

Some examples:

```
The code: if ((_f_NUMERO_TT == 97) || (_f_NUMERO_TT == JFP_23) || (_f_NUMERO_TT == YSTAR)) {

_f_NUMERO_TT == 97
```

F12 leads you to these snippets in some file that starts with #ifndef FILES_HEADER:

```
#define _f_NUMERO_TT            (_f_PARM_PROD.actu.desc_prod.num_TT) // _f_->input.produit_1[0].actu.desc_prod.num_TT

#define _f_PARM_PROD    (_f_INPUTS.produit_1[PACKAGE_PRODUIT_BASE]) 

    struct Inputs
    {
#define _f_INPUTS  (_f_->input)

        struct ParametersInputs
        {
#define _f_PARAMETERS   (_f_INPUTS.parameter) //_f_->input.parameter

            DATE date_fichiers;
            DATE date_fichiers_pp;
```

...

So instead of pasting "_f_NUMERO_TT" I need to replace it everywhere with

```
_f_->input.produit_1[0].actu.desc_prod.num_TT
```

Comment: You might create the preprocessed output file. See [how-do-i-see-a-c-c-source-file-after-preprocessing-in-visual-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277258/how-do-i-see-a-c-c-source-file-after-preprocessing-in-visual-studio) for details.

Comment: Find a solution that does not use macros.  Remove all your defines and write the code where is should be written.  Macros are not intended to save time writing code you that's where functions should be used. So anyway start by removing ALL your #define statements

Comment: And yes your conclusion is right, Either type _f_->input.produit_1[0].actu.desc_prod.num_TT   (which is not all that horrible) or create a function with input _f_ that returns the value you need

Comment: @PepijnKramer: Thx!

Where are macros for then?

It's horrible because everywhere these variables appear in the code, makes it a line that cannot be evaluated in the immediate window. To do it once, it's not that bad (although F12 is not working perfectly anymore, gets me to random locations in the code (right file though)) .
You suggest to just create a function to extract one particular value from that macro? But to get the code to work in the immidiate window, I should get rid of the macro alltogether I guess and somehow have the function extract it from a structure I create or so?

Comment: The best advise I can give you is to learn a bit of C++ first before trying to modify the existing code.  Specially the part about functions. https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/introduction-to-functions/.

Comment: Typically marcos are used to "inject" some kind of unique name into a variable or function name or function implementation. So they have their uses but the code you show is not one of them.

Comment: Visual Studio has a new feature to expand macros in the IDE. Does it help? https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/visualize-macro-expansion-for-c/

Comment: @PepijnKramer: I should, but you know, always hard to force your employer to give you enough time to learn.

Comment: @prapin: thx, I don't have it in version 17.7.6 but maybe I should upgrade

Comment: @babipsylon Wrong mindset of your employer. He should understand a little time spent now will save him a lot of time later. Tell him some very experienced developers told you this code is a disaster waiting to happen. It is not debuggable and it lacks unit tests and your predecessor made a right mess of it that you need to correct. His reaction will tell you a lot about wether you found a good workplace or not.

Answer (score 1):

You're right : This is absolutely horrible code. It's no surprise that there is no tooling support for code like this. That would only encourage people to continue with code like this, instead of fixing this. And there's no business case for tool makers.

I would recommend fixing the code. It appears that this code was written by a C developer, not a C++ developer. These macro's appear to be a poor substitute for inline methods. You can probably replace them incrementally.

While you're fixing it, translate the code as well. Having code in French decreases the pool of people who can maintain it by 95%. And some comments would be helpful, too.

This is clearly a case of technical debt. It's hard to judge how expensive this will be to fix, it could be anywhere between EUR 1 and EUR 100 per line of code. But that rapidly becomes a business decision, which is off-topic here.

Comment: Personally, I don't understand the point of renaming things 4 times. One time to get a shorter name and more readable code, ok.

Indeed it was initially developed in C, and it's still 99% C code.

How would inline methods help here? Would that mean the original variable name "_f_NUMERO_TT" could be evaluated by the debugger? For example in this case, would  the original script holding all the code with _f_NUMERO_TT   would still be readable? If you can give an example, would greatly help me understand how inline methods would work in this case.

Comment: "the original variable name _f_NUMERO_TT" - I understand that you're not a C++ developer. The root cause here is that _f_NUMERO_TT is **not** a variable name. It's a macro. Macro's are text replacement. It appears that the only variable here is `_f_`, and that's the only thing that the debugger can see. But the class of `_f_` could define an inline method `numero_tt` which returns `this->input.product_1[0].actu.desc_prod.num_TT `. You probably also want `_f_` to define `static constexpr int PackageProductBase = 0`. Since these are **real**  symbols, the debugger undestands them.

Comment: Yep indeed it's a macro. No, just did some Matlab and R Studio statistical programming, so this is all new to me.

Ok, so inside the class of _f_ I should create inline methods, so I can write something (I guess, a call to that specific inline method) in the "caller script" that retrieves the same value as _f_NUMERO_TT now does via macro and the debugger will understand that code.

Comment: Isn't "_f_" a pointer to ??  and "input" a member of the ?? (class?) to which this pointer "_f_ " references? No idea how and where to find the thing it points to however.

Ach, found something :
{int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
 Fichiers* _f_ = &_Fichiers_;}

Comment: @babipsylon: Ouch, that `_f_` pointer seems pretty stupid. As I said, you'll need to discuss with management how to bring this code into the 21st century.

Comment: So if you would want to make the debugger understand any line of code in the script while debugging, you need to retrieve values stored in _Fichiers_ in another way. You should probably have to implement something like an inline method, e.g. “numero_tt” inside this structure Fichiers or in a new class one has to make, which returns this->input.product_1[0].actu.desc_prod.num_TT whenever this method is called. Code will probably be as readable for the layman code reader, with the advantage that the debugger/Immediate window will understand it.

Comment: Yep, the business question how to alter is another story :). Just trying to understand the technical side of it. If I can summarize what you suggest to do, if one time there is a budget:

Comment: "script" is another dangerous term. C++ is not interpreted, it's compiled. The debugger has to do a lot of work to simulate what happening at C++ level given only the CPU state. The CPU has zero idea which line of source code it's executing, for instance. The debugger can look at the _symbol table_, but that only contains the real symbols, not macro names.

Comment: Don't know how to call a piece of code in .cpp file then :). Yep seems like debugging was a lot easier in Matlab :( .

Answer (score 1):

To give an example on how you can use (member) functions :

```
#include <iostream>

struct DATE
{
    int day {1};
    int month {1};
    int year {1971};
};


struct Inputs
{
// #define _f_INPUTS  (_f_->input)

        struct ParametersInputs
        {
// #define _f_PARAMETERS   (_f_INPUTS.parameter) //_f_->input.parameter

            DATE date_fichiers;
            DATE date_fichiers_pp;
        } ;

    ParametersInputs parameters[2];

    // add a member function to Inputs that can do all the internal indirections
    int get_year(std::size_t parameter_index)
    {
        return parameters[parameter_index].date_fichiers.year;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Inputs inputs;
    std::cout << inputs.get_year(0); // now use a function 
    // note there is NO checking so using 2 instead of 0 will not be correct 
    // since you will be accessing parameters array in Inputs out of bound

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will study this code tomorrow in detail!