Getting preprocessor and compiler output in VS 2022
Because I wanted to learn more about the preprocessor, I enabled "Preprocess to a file" for my project (project properties, C/C++, preprocessor), so it looked like this:

However, at some point, I noticed that I do not get compiler warnings any more, and sure enough, that's documented:

The /P option suppresses compilation. It does not produce an .obj file, even if you use /Fo (Object File Name).

Now, that's very inconvenient. I'd like to have a look at both, the result of the preprocessor and get compiler errors. Is it possible to achieve that in Visual Studio 2022?

Are you using Visual Studio with CMake? In that case, a custom command could be used to generate the desired files as some kind of "by-product". Still the source files have to be processed twice but it could be at least automated... (Actually, CMake does nothing else when generating solution, project files, and batch files. So, it could be done without CMake as well, of course.)

open Configuration Manager and create another configuration, the one that dumps preprocessor file, you can create as many configurations as you like for the same project with any different defines and flags as you like

@Scheff'sCat: no, we're not using CMake yet. Sorry.

It's usually not possible with most toolchains or build management tools (IDEs, makefiles, etc), because the C++ standard describes a set of sequential phases of translation and (although there are variations between implementations) capturing output from one phase is usually treated as a requirement to NOT execute later phases (so not produce diagnostics that those later phases would produce).   Preprocessing is phase 4, "compilation" is phase 7, and "linking" is phase 9.  So capturing preprocessor output typically suppresses compilation and linking entirely.

You can have separate build targets - one that captures preprocessor output, and one that does a complete build.    It's also (a little more difficult, but possible) to set up a series of targets that captures preprocessor output to a file, renames that file so it is treated like a source file, and then compiles it.  A consequence of doing it that way (may be an advantage or a disadvantage, depending on your viewpoint) is that diagnostics then reference line numbers of code in the preprocessed output - which will be different to line numbers in the original source file.

@Peter: The more I know about C++, the worse it gets... The information is available. hat's the problem of writing it to disk? Holy cow...

This isn't a C++ problem.   It's a case of you expecting an implementation to do something that most developers don't need or even want.  There is no problem of writing preprocessor output to disk. But you want an implementation (toolchain) to write preprocessor output to disk, and THEN continue executing the rest of the build process.  Although that would be easy for an implementation to do if required, developers (using the toolchain) usually don't want/need it. Compiler vendors don't wear the cost of implementing features that few developers demand.

In addition to @Peter's comments, I think one reason such dual output is usually not implemented is that the C++ standard only requires those compilation phases to happen "as-if", meaning that the actual implementation may not exactly follow these, as long as the end result is the same. And, if I remember correctly, Microsoft's C++ compiler in particular is a "single pass compiler", i.e., there is no separate "preprocessing" pass, everything is parsed and compiled in one pass only. In the early days of C, yes, there was a separate tool called preprocessor, but nowadays the is no need for that.

@heapunderrun has it changed with MSVC? It has always had some options to preprocess only. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277258/how-do-i-see-a-c-c-source-file-after-preprocessing-in-visual-studio

@ÖöTiib MSVC still has those options to PP only (instead of compiling). But translation phases may be fused together, see footnote 7 under lex.phases. For example, as briefly outlined on Cppreference, phase 3: lexing formally involves "reverting" certain transformations from previous phases. But if compiler knows you aren't interested in PP-out, it can reorder instead of reverting, compiling may start before PP finishes, or in another optimized order.

@heapunderrun: I would accept that as an answer. It's a good enough reason for me.
